# Disable Alt+F4 in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

i have some user control and i want to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> oportunity for the end user. When my User Control shows, there is opportunity to close it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>,  then program goes to base class in the method:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Content = null; // Remove child from logical parent - for reusing purposes
    this.RemoveLogicalChild(Content); //this works faster
    base.OnClosing(e);
    { GC.Collect(); };
}
```

What i must do here or somewhere else, to do disable my user control closing on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>?

Comment: I need to ask you: why do you need to do this? ALT+F4 has been an established method of closing applications as long as Windows has been around. I does not strike me as a brilliant idea to remove this option from the user. A better idea, in my opinion, would be to make sure that your application gracefully handles it.

Comment: I only need to do this only in one custom UserControl, where i need to disable Esc and Alt+F4, so the user wouldnt be able to workaround business scenario.

Comment: If I were your user and I would dislike to complete the business scenario, I would kill the process to not have to going on with it:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be sure, I would really question this as a *Best Practice*.  However, if you really want to do this, then you need to prevent the window containing the `UserControl` from closing.

The easiest way to do this is to set a `DependencyProperty` on your `UserControl` that is simply a `Boolean` that flags whether the container can be closed.  You would only set this to true when you want it to actually close (you probably already have a button or something that you are using now to close the control).

```
public Boolean AllowClose
{
    get { return (Boolean)GetValue(AllowCloseProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AllowCloseProperty, value); }
}

 public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowCloseProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("AllowClose", typeof(Boolean), 
    typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

Then, in the windows `Closing` event, you would check for that property to be set to `true`.  If it is not, then you would set `e.Cancel = true`;

Using your example:

```
   protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
   {
    if (! myUserControl.AllowClose)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Even though most Windows allow Alt-F4 to close, I'm not letting you!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Content = null; // Remove child from parent - for reuse
        this.RemoveLogicalChild(Content); //this works faster
        base.OnClosing(e);
        { GC.Collect(); };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

On your custom control add the following handlers:
PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
PreviewKeyUp="Window_PreviewKeyUp"

The implementation for the handlers:

```
    bool AltDown = false;
    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)
        {
            AltDown = true;
        }
        else if (e.SystemKey == Key.F4 && AltDown)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }            
    }
    private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)
        {
            AltDown = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

you can override the OnPreviewkeyDown method and trap ALT and F4 keys.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt)) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.F4))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another decent method is :

```cs
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && e.SystemKey == Key.F4)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to block <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is to block only <kbd>F4</kbd>.
So, when <kbd>F4</kbd> doesn't need to be handled, blocking <kbd>Alt</kbd> is unnecessary.

Hope that's useful.